# how to read for a certain symbol in a string

Tags: php

I am trying to separate 2 symbols from a string and then
count how many of these symbols there are.

So if i had : `1110001110000`

Then it should find that there are 6= 1's and 7= 0's

So This is what I have tried:
Essentially what I need, is to read the string indexes in code would be `string[$i]` then `IF` there is a `1` or a `0` count it.

I tried using a `for`-loop

```
for ($i=0; $i < $getInput[$i] ; $i++) { 
    if ($getInput[$i] == 1) {
        echo "ONE";
    } elseif ($getInput[$i] == 0) {
        echo "ZERO";
    }   
}
```

Here im trying to echo out `ONE` for everytime ther is a 1 and `ZERO` for everytime theres a zero.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($getInput as $key) {
    echo $key;
}
```

here i tried to utilize a `foreach`, here I am not really declaring to see for One index, i tried putting a for each in a `for` but needless to say, it didn't work.

Comment: This should be helpful - http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: `array_count_values(str_split('1110001110000'))` does the job for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using substr_count, you can do this in a fairly straightforward way:

```
echo substr_count("1110001110000", '1'); //Echos 6
echo substr_count("1110001110000", '0'); //Echos 7
```

Comment: Indeed exactly what I asked for, but is there a way that essentially counts the first few symbols,  then refers to code and then echo'es out a declared something, in practice it would look like this: `1110001110000` = ABAC; So essentially, 111= A, 000= B, 0000=C. considering the String can be random patterns of 1's and 0's

Comment: That would require a bit of logic programming on your end, way out of scope for what the substr_count function can do. If you are receiving a string in which you have no idea what it contains, this wont be trivial I feel.

Answer (score 1):

Substr_count.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

```
$str = "1110001110000";

Echo "there is " .substr_count($str, "0") ." zeros \n";
Echo "there is " .substr_count($str, "1") ." ones \n";
```

https://3v4l.org/BQEiR

---

If you want to output it as your code implies (one one one zero) you can use numberformatter.
Here I split the string to an array and loop through it and output the spellout of each number.

```
$str = "1110001110000";
$arr = str_split($str);

$nf = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
Foreach($arr as $numb){
    echo $nf->format($numb) . " ";
}
```

Output:

```
one one one zero zero zero one one one zero zero zero zero
```

https://3v4l.org/nHX59